# Wordpress database - You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: database, wordpress, syntax

I have following code:

```
<?php

        $exists_photos = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $dsp_galleries_photos galleries, $dsp_user_albums_table albums WHERE galleries.album_id=albums.album_id AND galleries.status_id=1 AND galleries.album_id IN ($ids1) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6");

         $i=0;

         foreach ($exists_photos as $user_photos) { 

            $photo_id=$user_photos->gal_photo_id;

            $album_id1=$user_photos->album_id;

            $file_name=$user_photos->image_name;

            $private=$user_photos->private_album;

            $image_path="/wp-content/uploads/dsp_media/user_photos/user_".$member_id."/album_".$album_id1."/".$file_name;

            if(($i%3)==0){

            ?>
```

It returns following error:

```
WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1 for query SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_dsp_galleries_photos WHERE status_id=1 AND album_id IN () made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/ArtSee/page.php'), the_content, apply_filters('the_content'), call_user_func_array, do_shortcode, preg_replace_callback, do_shortcode_tag, call_user_func, wp_include_file, include('/plugins/dsp/profile_header.php'), include('/plugins/dsp/member_dsp_header.php'), include('/plugins/dsp/headers/view_profile_header.php'), include('/plugins/dsp/view_profile_setup.php')
```

Suggestions will be appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You missed a VALUE INSIDE `()`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_dsp_galleries_photos WHERE status_id=1 AND album_id IN ()
```

The statement: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')'` indicates the point of failure. I refers to the second `)` in :

```
... album_id IN () ...
```

In any case your code does not show this part.

Comment: NomikOS, thanks. I am a somewhat loss.  It is ....album_id IN ($ids1)  not .album_id IN ()

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM $dsp_galleries_photos galleries, $dsp_user_albums_table albums
```

should be

```
SELECT * FROM dsp_galleries_photos galleries, dsp_user_albums_table albums
```

with no $ before the table name - you also should consider if you really need to select * but that won't impact the syntax of the query

Comment: Those are PHP variables. If you look at the error you can see that they are converted to proper table names before the SQL executes-- ie., `wp_dsp_galleries_photos`. That is not where the error is.

Comment: I was always taught that you needed to escape $ signs in table names so it would either have to be something like SELECT * FROM `$dsp_galleries_photos` galleries or it was a typo on the part of the poster - my mistake

Comment: Also the code posted doesn't actually contain the code shown in the error which was another reason I jumped on the table name

Comment: That is a double-quoted PHP string. The variables will be substituted before the MySQL database sees it. You wouldn't want to escape that unless your table name had a literal `$` in it, or you would get an error.

Comment: I have upvoted your comment but it really isn't obvious from the code whether it is a PHP string or a table name and the fact the error shown doesn't actually refer to the code posted makes it a poor question